# change json structure in Django

Tags: django

I've never had to change json structure before using Django models, so I may have made a completely stupid question.

I have some data in my database and want to parse it in a json format. 
My view.py (a bit simplified) is:

```
def get_json(request):
    pos = Pos.objects.filter(id=1).values('lat', 'lon','id')
    return JsonResponse ({'position': list(pos)})
```

As a result I get this json object:

```
{ "position": [{"lat": "21", "id": 1, "lon": "21"}, {"lat": "22", "id": 1, "lon": "22"}, {"lat": "23", "id": 1, "lon": "23"}]}
```

In order to reduce the volume of unusefull data, I need to get a json structure like this:

```
{"id":"1", "position":{"lats":[21,22,23], "longs":[21,22,22]} }
```

I would be gratefull if sombody could help me

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to process the data; you can do whatever you like within the view function.

```
pos = Pos.objects.filter(id=1).values('lat', 'lon','id')
data = {"lats": [], "longs": []}
for p in pos:
    data["lats"].append(p['lat'])
    data["longs"].append(p['long'])
return JsonResponse({'position': data})
```

Comment: You can just access the nested values: `data["position"][0]["lats"]`.

Comment: Thank you now I can modify the json objects according with my needs

Comment: Hi Daniel, imagine that I need to have initially lats and longs array with 0 values. "lats": [0,0,0], "longs": [0,0,0] until I send the json data lats and longs "lats":[21,22,23], "longs":[21,22,22]. How can I do that? Thank you very much for your help